# Adding KML layers to ArcGIS JS API v4 (beta)?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, kml

I have been building a web application using ArcGIS JS API v4.0.Beta1. I am having difficulties finding out how to add KML layers to the scene. How do I add the KMLs? I have tried adding a new feature layer with the URL from the host server and I am having no luck.

Example of what I've tried that doesn't work:

```
var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
url: "[insert KML url here]",
mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT
```

Any ideas?

Additionally: [Here is my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/csloan93/pj9rwvg4/2/) if you wanted to take a look for yourself

Here is my current .js as of 8/5/2015:

```
var map, view;

require([
  "esri/Map",
  "esri/views/SceneView",
  "esri/layers/KMLLayer",
  "dojo/dom",
  "dojo/on",
  "dojo/domReady!"
  "dojo/parser", 
  "dojo/dom-style",
], 
function (Map, SceneView, KMLLayer, domStyle, parser) {

  //Create map
  map = new Map({
    basemap: "topo"
  });

  //Create SceneView
  view = new SceneView({
    map: map,
    container: "viewDiv",
    camera: {
      position: [-105.581, 41.305, 3000],
      tilt: 45
    }
  });

    parser.parse();

    var kmlURL = 'http://uwyo.maps.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/457a85b101ba4fb6a159d4ea16c75153/data';
    var kml = new esri.layers.KMLLayer(kmlURL);
    map.addLayer(kml);
      kml.on("load", function() {
      domStyle.set("loading", "display", "none");
      });



});
```

Comment: From my initial browse of the 4.0beta API, the new API does not (yet?) include the 3.x KMLLayer class for use with KML data. The ESRI sample page in case you haven't already found it: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/layers_kml.html

Comment: Yeah, I'm not finding much either. I'll keep looking. Thanks for searching too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 4.0 beta 1 does not support KML.  The KMLLayer will be supported in a future beta version.

Beta 1 only supports the modules documented in the [API Reference](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/beta/api-reference/).

Answer (score -1):

Create a `KMLLayer` and add it to the map.

```
var kmlURL = 'http://www.lohneswright.com/ctc/kml/actc_wheels.kml';
var kml = new esri.layers.KMLLayer(kmlURL);
map.addLayer(kml);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. Where did you find this section of code from?

Comment: Perhaps you have not added the necessary library!

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Do you have added the necessary js files?

Comment: This is just a guess! May be correct or incorrect diagnosis with you!